# Avoid control-B is "eaten"

Tags: wysiwyg

I am a heavy EMACS user. On the Mac I get EMACS keybindings in most text fields, and on most websites. However, if I am on a drupal website editing an HTML field, control-b toggles bold. Command-B should toggle bold; control-b should move me back a character.

Is it possible to fix this, on either my client or on the Drupal server?

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the CKeditor's javascript library rather than drupal. There are several sites and questions around on how to do this, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668043/how-to-configure-shortcut-keys-in-ck-editor-4-not-finding-plugin-for-keystrocks). I haven't tried this, but my guess is that you need to modify the config.js file that lives in your /sites/all/library/ckeditor folder of your drupal installation.

Comment: But don't hack core. This may be overridable with a custom module loading Javascript.

Comment: This may not technically be "hacking core" - the config.js file is there for the user to add specific configurations - including new custom shortcuts